# Returning best support vectors from support vector machine

Tags: python, vector, scikit-learn, svm

I'm using a support vector classifier from sklearn (in Python) to find the optimal boundary between a set of "0" and "1" labelled data.

See: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html

However I want to perform some analysis after rotating the data about the boundary line and therefore I need to return the properties which will allow me to define the line to start with.

I carry out the SVC as follows:

Relevant imports:

```
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I define the classifier as:

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear',C = 1e-3 ,class_weight='balanced')
```

Which is then fit to the training data:

```
clf.fit(f_train, labels_train)
```

Whereupon the linear class boundary can be viewed using:

```
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()
xx = np.linspace(xlim[0], xlim[1], 30)
yy = np.linspace(ylim[0], ylim[1], 30)
YY, XX = np.meshgrid(yy, xx)
xy = np.vstack([XX.ravel(), YY.ravel()]).T
Z = clf.decision_function(xy).reshape(XX.shape)
ax.contour(XX, YY, Z, colors='k', levels=[-1, 0, 1], alpha=0.5,
           linestyles=['--', '-', '--'])
```

As seen in: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane.html

But when calling:

```
clf.support_vectors_.shape
```

I'm not sure how to interpret the output as being relevant if trying to describe the linear boundary as the output has shape (4485, 2)

Any help with returning something that will allow me to define the boundary line will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your requirement is not clear to me. Do you want to get the boundary line? .decision_function() would give the distance from that boundary line. If you give a mess grid, you can get the boundary line itself.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm trying to find any way in which I can explicitly define the calculated boundary line so I need to get to y = mx + c and I thought that using the support vectors might be the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Plotting 3D Decision Boundary From Linear SVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232334/plotting-3d-decision-boundary-from-linear-svm) you can get a boundary line using `clf.intercept_` and `clf.coef_` attributes:

```
def decision_hyperplane(clf, x, y=None, dimension=2):
    """
    Return a decision line (dimension 2, return y based on x) or a 
    decision plane (dimension 3, return z based on x and y).

    Decision plane equation is wx + b = 0, so in 2d case:
    w.dot(x) + b = w_x * x + w_y * y + b = 0
    y = (-w_x * x - b) / w_y
    In 3d:
    w_x * x + w_y * y + w_z * z + b = 0
    z = (-w_x * x - w_y * y - b) / w_z
    """
    if dimension == 2:
        return (-clf.intercept_[0] - clf.coef_[0][0] * x) / clf.coef_[0][1]
    elif dimension == 3:
        return (-clf.intercept_[0] - clf.coef_[0][0] * x - clf.coef_[0][1] * y) / clf.coef_[0][2]
```

If you use it with your code like this

`ax.plot(xx, decision_hyperplane(clf, xx), color='red')`

the result will be[image]